# Change Lightning buttonIcon image source to static resource

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to swap out the icon image used in `lightning:buttonIcon` on-click to one that's in a static resource. However, this is removing the SVG icon when the button is clicked.

**Component:**

```
<lightning:buttonIcon aura:id="previewIcon" iconName="utility:preview" class="show-password__icon" onclick="{!c.togglePassword}" alternativeText="Show password" />
```

**Controller:**

```
component.find("previewIcon").set("v.iconName", "{!$Resource.FutureStatePortalV1 + '/assets/style/images/SVG/previde-hide.svg'}");
```

Is there a different way to reference a static resource in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. It's simply not supported at this time. The only supported format is "category:name", where category is a value like "action", and name is a value like "upload". If you want to include your own SVG elements, you can go for it, but you'll need to use something like the [SVG Helper](https://archive-2_1_4.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper). There's no native support for SVG/USE combinations in Lightning as of yet, because of the security risks involved.